# delete indexed page from google

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot

I want to delete all page indexed in google and use url seo to index my page again using url seo and delete old urls. I tried

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

but does not work.

for example i'm using mybb platform and thread urls is:

> http://myforum.com/thread-33-post-4.html

after install google seo plugin my thread url is:

> http://myforum.com/thread-how-to-ask-question.html

I want to update google and replace old url with new url. or delete all google indexed page in bulk.

please help.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Google has instructions for deleting pages:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

They say to visit the url removal tool:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal

Generally if you want to replace a url with a different one, you configure your server to do a permanent redirect from the old url to the new one....

Comment: yes but do i need to do a redirect for every urls? i want in bulk or how to do  permanent redirect for all url in htaccess? thanks

Comment: This answer might be what you're after: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91057/redirecting-all-pages-to-new-website-homepage-using-htaccess